# Why does a system want to achieve randomness to be feasible?

Tags: thermodynamics

According to entropy and gibbs free energy, randomness is one of the factors that determines reaction spontaneity, but why? Shouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unanswerable unless you edit it and give more context. What are your underlying assumptions about randomness and spontaneity, and how are they in conflict with experimental data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randomness is not the correct word to use as it is ambiguous in this context. What happens is that the molecules' energy is spread out among as many energy levels as possible, i.e. the number of possible ways of filling the energy levels is maximised and this number produces what we call the entropy. It is an experimental observation that this happens.

In a thermodynamic explanation when using just the first law the external work performed in a reaction must be equal to the heat loss, unless some heat is given to or taken from the surroundings. This is the point first clearly realised by Gibbs. If an isothermal reaction runs reversibly $T\Delta S$  is the heat absorbed from the surroundings, and if this is positive the work done ($\Delta G$) will be greater than the heat of reaction. Thus you can see that as $\Delta G = \Delta H-T\Delta S$  the entropy can be used towards changing the free energy. When the number of ways of arranging the energy among the numerous energy levels is greater in the products than in the reactants $\Delta S$ will be positive and tend to make $\Delta G$ negative and 'spontaneity'.